# How to type react custom hooks to use with context in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a usersDataContext that has a useUserData custom hook to update the data, I use a common recipe that works with vanilla JS, but TypeScript is not happy about it:

```js
import { createContext, useState, useCallback } from "react";

export type usersData = {
  data: any;
  isLoading: boolean;
  status: string;
};

export interface usersDataContext {
  usersData: usersData;
  setUsersData: () => void;
}

const UsersContext = createContext<usersDataContext>({
  usersData: {
    data: [],
    isLoading: false,
    status: "",
  },
  setUsersData: () => {},
});

export const useUsersData = () => {
  const [newData, setNewData] = useState<usersData>({
    data: [],
    isLoading: false,
    status: "",
  });

  const setUsersData = useCallback((data: usersData) => {
    setNewData(data);
  }, []);
  return {
    newData,
    setUsersData,
  };
};

export default UsersContext;
```

I try to pass the hook as a value for the context provider in my index.tsx like this :

```js
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const usersData = useUsersData();
 
  return (
    <UsersContext.Provider value={usersData}>
...
```

I'm getting an error :

```js
Property 'usersData' is missing in type '{ newData: usersData; setUsersData: (data: usersData) => void; }' but required in type 'usersDataContext'.ts(2741)

usersContext.ts(10, 3): 'usersData' is declared here.

index.d.ts(338, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<usersDataContext>'



(JSX attribute) ProviderProps<usersDataContext>.value: usersDataContext
```

how can I correctly type this hook so the error goes away?

Comment: If you want a hook to conform the interface, don't call the property newData. It's usersData

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues.

Use (have added type information to input of `setUsersData`)

```
export interface usersDataContext {
  usersData: usersData;
  setUsersData: (data: usersData) => void;
}
```

instead of

```
export interface usersDataContext {
  usersData: usersData;
  setUsersData: () => void;
}
```

And

Use (have changed `newData` to `usersData`)

```
export const useUsersData = () => {
  const [usersData, setNewData] = useState<usersData>({
    data: [],
    isLoading: false,
    status: ""
  });

  const setUsersData = useCallback((data: usersData) => {
    setNewData(data);
  }, []);
  return {
    usersData,
    setUsersData
  };
};
```

instead of

```
export const useUsersData = () => {
  const [newData, setNewData] = useState<usersData>({
    data: [],
    isLoading: false,
    status: "",
  });

  const setUsersData = useCallback((data: usersData) => {
    setNewData(data);
  }, []);
  return {
    newData,
    setUsersData,
  };
};
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-fermi-eg8jg?file=/src/UsersContext.tsx

Comment: @João Pedro, check this out!!